# Delegatecall equivalent in Soroban Smart contracts

Tags: security, smart-contract

Is there an equivalent function to [delegatecall](https://solidity-by-example.org/delegatecall/) in Soroban Smart Contracts?

We are building test cases for potential vulnerabilities in Soroban contracts, and were wondering if there is an equivalent that allows for the creation of proxy contracts.